# How to check if Fourier components are in phase of out of phase?

Tags: fourier-transform, phase, fourier-series, fourier

I have a time series (of 23 timestamps) of which I take the Fourier transform. Now the fourier transform has 23 imaginary values and each has an amplitude and a phase. When I get the phase angle, it given me arctan value of the angle. Now how can I determine if two fourier coefficients are in phase or out of phase.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the phase reference point in time.

Depending on the reference point, every DFT basis sinusoid can be either in-phase or out-of-phase (by 180 degrees) with every other basis, thus the same with any coefficient weighting of these basis vectors.

If you reference phase to the center of a DFT (using an fftshift), then the angle will tell you whether a particular component has even or odd symmetry relative to the center.

Comment: So in my case I get 23 complex values after fourier transform, I can check for each fourier coefficient that the phase would be arctan(imaginary_part/real_part). Now I have this value for all the coefficients. Can I compare these values to find if two coefficients are in phase or out of phase?

Comment: Not without specifying a reference point.

Comment: can you please provide me a link where I can read more about finding the "reference point" or describe in brief here?